# How many user can be created on amazon EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hi im planning to setup ftp server on amazon Ec2 window instance i want to know that how many ftp users can amazon Ec2 window instance allows?

Answer (score 4):

Because you have root access to the machine, you can set up as many as you'd like.